# Как вывести стандартные коэффициенты регрессии на график с помощью команды plot_model в R

Tags: r, rstudio

Прохожу курс по эконометрике, столкнулся на нем с необходимостью работать в R, до этого опыта работы с языками программирования или чем-либо близким не было, на занятии преподаватель показал, как сделать это с помощью команды "sjp.lm", но такой команды у меня нет. Обнаружил, что эту команду заменили на "plot_model", нашел как вывести значения коэффициентов бета на график, через "show.values = TRUE", но уже два дня потратил, чтобы понять как вывести значение R^2, adj.R^2, B0 и т.д. Если кто знает, подскажите, как с помощью указанной в заголовке команды добиться вывода данных коэффициентов на график.
Скрипт по которому учусь:
h <- swiss
glimpse(h)
help(swiss)

model <- lm(data=h, Fertility ~ Catholic + Agriculture + Examination)
summary(model)

coeftest(model)
confint(model)
sjp.lm(model)

Мой скрипт:
h <- swiss
glimpse(h)
help(swiss)

model <- lm(data=h, Fertility ~ Catholic + Agriculture + Examination)
summary(model)

coeftest(model)
confint(model)
plot_model(model, show.values = TRUE)

Comment: Добрый день. Попрошу убрать скриншот и добавить текстом код и ошибку

Comment: @RottenRat сделано.